How to share link to Snapchat using Swift?
I'm trying to find a way to open snapchat using the snapchat:// scheme so I can pass a link to the share screen (see attached image), but I always get the "Something went wrong" alert.
Here's what I've tried:
let shareString = "snapchat://text=\(text)&url=https://www.google.com"
let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

let shareString = "snapchat://url=https://www.google.com"
let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

let shareString = "snapchat://text=https://www.google.com"
let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my .plist entry for the schemes:


take a look at this

I have seen it and it shows the same error alert

I think you have not define snapchat url scheme in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in Info.plist.
Here is document link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14

No I have added snapchat to the list

Can you provide your screenshot of Info.plist file?

I added it to my question
